# Would it be appropriate to semi-update request using HTTP PUT?

Tags: rest, http-method

Assuming I have the following json for update using PATCH.

```
{
    "person" : {
        "name" : "ABC"
        "sex" : "M"
    },
    "contact" : {
        "mobileno" : "12341234"
    }
}
```

So if this user can only update contact and the above json is passed in.

Do I process the json, accepting contact and rejecting person. 
Or i reject right from the start?

Comment: does the client not know only contact can be updated? If it does know, it should only be sending contact

Comment: @codebrane yes they know. I am trying to prevent client from doing what they are not suppose to do

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially defensive programming where you know the outside world is generating inappropriate output.

If I was using Java I'd use Jackson and create a class, perhaps:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class PersonPatch {
  private Contact contact;
  ... setters/getters...
}

class Contact {
  private String mobileno;
  ... setters/getters...
}
```

and deserialise the JSON using the `PersonPatch` class. This automatically ignores everything else in the JSON.

Is it appropriate? I don't see why not as it removes unnecessary input, cleaning up what the client is sending.